# Jquery ajax and cyrillic letters: something strange

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cyrillic

I have such input:

```
<input type="text" name="enternum" id="enternum" size="100" onkeyup="searchordernet(this.value);">
```

Also have such javascript on my page:

```
<script>
var timer;
function searchordernet (qstringer) {
  clearTimeout(timer);
  var lengther = qstringer.length;
  if (lengther > 3) {
    timer = setTimeout(function() {
      $('#flower').show();
      qstringer = encodeURIComponent(qstringer);
      $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'script.php',
        data: 'generator='+qstringer
      }).done(function(datax){
        $('#flower').html(datax);
        alert(qstringer);
      });
    }, 500);
  }
}
```

When I enter comething like "зинь" into input - script works fine. When I enter e.g. "харе" it doesn't work, even no alert. When I change enter "харк" - everything works fine

Any ideas?

Comment: What is `qstringer.length`? Expected one or not?

Comment: var lengther = qstringer.length;
  if (lengther > 3) { ...code... } , input text has 4 letters

Comment: Ya, but when you enter `"харе"`, is length equal 4 or not? That was my question. So is ajax request send? Have you got any error in console? What returns request when not working? Etc, etc... Could be some encoding issue server side or client side regarding character encoding

Comment: when I add alert before or after ajax - it shows. when i enter "харе" (cyrillic letters) - once, when e.g. "зинь" - twice (two alerts in script)

Comment: But you have to debug it, not just using some random alert() that didn't help at all

Comment: I used Firefox console. What I have: when I enter "харе" -  [HTTP/1.1 200 OK], no action. "харев" - same, "харева" - same. "хареваа" - [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 61ms] and shows result